# Handling 2 ajax post on same page php, the both ajax post to same page no url in post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I need to handle 2 post on the same page to process 2 different php code.

First POST after validating if all fields has valid data this will then enable another block, here in the new block will be more inputs, after second block is enable then I need to the second POST , on the second POST is where I'm struggling I cannot get echo of second POST.

Is like having 2 forms, after form1 is submitted on same page, this enable a new form (form2), then validate form 2 data from second ajax post, with the data from the second Post i will execute a php function.

I did had the 2 forms as proper html, but form2 was always got submitted, even with the prevent defautl form as was always submitting and this made a lot of conflicts on my page.

```
<html>
<header>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

</header>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center alternate-background">
        <main class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
            <h1 class="form-signin-heading mt-4 mb-3 alternate-background"> Llene los 2 campos para validar sus numero de cliente y rif</h1>
            <div id="test" style="hide"></div>
            <form method="post" id="a">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book" id="book" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" name="validate" id="validate">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
//error_reporting ( E_ALL );
//ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );
//if( isset($_POST['ajax1']) && isset($_POST['bookId']) ){

if (isset($_POST['bookId'])) {

    if (empty(trim($_POST['bookId'])) || empty(trim($_POST['book']))) {
        echo 'Some fields are empty. the post came empty';
    }
    else {

        $projectid = $_POST['bookId'];
        $projecti = $_POST['book'];
        echo $projectid;
        echo $projecti;
        echo '
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center alternate-background">
              <main class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
                <h1 class="form-signin-heading mt-4 mb-3 alternate-background"> porfavor crear su usuario y contraseña</h1>
                
                  <form  method="post" id="a2">
                  
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <label id="username-label" class="col-form-label col-12 col-md-4 text-md-right text-md-end">Usuario *</label>
                      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <span id="usernameCheck" class="small"></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" value="" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="username">
                      </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <label for="fname" id="fname-label" class="col-form-label col-12 col-md-4 text-md-right text-md-end">Nombre *</label>
                      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Nombre" value="" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="given-name">
                      </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                      <div class="submit btn btn-primary "  id="registerUser">
                        <span class="fa fa-user-plus mr-2 me-2"></span> Registrarse          
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                  </form>
                  
              </main>
            </div>
          </div>
       ';
    }
}
else {
    //echo "both must be filled";
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

    $projecx = $_POST['username'];
    $projecxx = $_POST['fname'];
    echo $projecx;
    echo $projecxx;
    // show the data
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#registerUser").click(function () {

        var usernn = $("#username").val();
        var usernnn = $("#fname").val();
        console.log(usernn);
        console.log(usernnn);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {username: usernn, fname: usernnn}
            /*
            success: function(data) {
               jQuery(".res").html(data);
               $("#test").html(data);
               console.log(data);
            }
            */
        });
    });

    $("#validate").click(function () {

        console.log("The paragraph was clicked.");
        var unc = $("#bookId").val();
        var rif = $("#book").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {bookId: unc, book: rif}

            success: function (data) {
                jQuery(".res").html(data);
                $("#test").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put the `$("#registerUser").click(function(){....})` action inside the block where the system will display the container.

In this way the system, when rendering the container block, can correctly link with the click action.

So, based on your code, please revise to the following to see the effect please:

```
<html>
<header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
        </script>

          </header>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-md-center alternate-background">
      <main class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
        <h1 class="form-signin-heading mt-4 mb-3 alternate-background"> Llene los 2 campos para validar sus numero de cliente y rif</h1>
       
              <div id="test" style="hide"></div>
                <form  method="post" id="a">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book" id="book" value="">
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" name="validate" id="validate">Update</button>
                   </div>
               </form>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
 

    
<?php   
    if (isset($_POST['bookId'])) {
          if (empty(trim($_POST['bookId'])) || empty(trim($_POST['book'])) ) {
           echo 'Some fields are empty. the post came empty';
          } else {  
                                   
          $projectid = $_POST['bookId'];    
          $projecti = $_POST['book'];   
          echo $projectid;
          echo $projecti;   
          echo '
          <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center alternate-background">
          <main class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
      
      <h1 class="form-signin-heading mt-4 mb-3 alternate-background"> porfavor crear su usuario y contraseña</h1>
       <form  method="post" id="a2">
      <div class="row mb-3">
          <label id="username-label" class="col-form-label col-12 col-md-4 text-md-right text-md-end">Usuario *</label>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
            <span id="usernameCheck" class="small"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" value="" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="username">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row mb-3">
          <label for="fname" id="fname-label" class="col-form-label col-12 col-md-4 text-md-right text-md-end">Nombre *</label>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Nombre" value="" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="given-name">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-4">
          <div class="submit btn btn-primary "  id="registerUser">
            <span class="fa fa-user-plus mr-2 me-2"></span> Registrarse          </div>
              </div>
       </form >
        </main>
        </div>
        </div>
       ';
?>
<script> 

$("#registerUser").click(function(){
alert('ok');

var usernn = $("#username").val();
var usernnn = $("#fname").val();
alert( usernn);
alert( usernnn);

//PLEASE put other code here 

                 });
               </script>
<?php
        }
      } else {          
            //echo "both must be filled";
        }
        
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    
         $projecx = $_POST['username']; 
        $projecxx = $_POST['fname'];    
          echo $projecx;
         echo $projecxx;        
         // show the data   
          }
         ?>
    
  
  <script type="text/javascript">

    
               $("#validate").click(function(){
              console.log("The paragraph was clicked.");
               var unc = $("#bookId").val();
                  var rif = $("#book").val();
           
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {bookId: unc, book: rif }
                 
                success: function(data){
                   jQuery(".res").html(data);

                 $("#test").html(data);

                }
                });
                
                              });

                         </script>
                      </body>
                       </html>
```